# Beethoven's masses

Tags: classical-music

I've checked on Wikipedia and other biographies on Beethoven but I can't seem to find any other masses he did apart from the one in C Major. Does anyone know any others or even better,  could someone refer me to where I can find more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beethoven wrote only one other Mass: the [Mass in D Major, Op. 123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missa_solemnis_(Beethoven)), called the *Missa Solemnis* (*Solemn Mass*). It was premiered in 1824 in St. Petersburg, Russia. It was written around the same time as his 9th Symphony. While it was considered to be a great achievement, the earlier [Mass in C, Op. 86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_C_major_(Beethoven)) from 1807 has proven more popular over the years.

Beethoven wrote a German-language sacred oratorio, [*Christus am Ölberge*, Op.85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_on_the_Mount_of_Olives_(Beethoven)) (*Christ on the Mount of Olives*), to a libretto by Franz Huber. It is Beethoven's only oratorio. It was not considered successful and is rarely performed.

Beethoven, historically, was a notable example of a great composer who earned his own way without relying on patronage; that is to say that he did not have a period of his career where he worked full-time for a church, a ruler, or a nobleman's court. That may be why he wrote relatively little religious music. Many well-known composers before him wrote a great deal of church music because they were specifically commissioned to do so by their employers on a regular basis.

To find a large list (not completely exhaustive) of compositions by any composer before the 20th century, always check the listings at [imslp.org](http://imslp.org), the **International Music Score Library Project**. They provide free downloadable scores for a great deal of music that is in the public domain.

[IMSLP scores for Beethoven's Mass in D Major, Op. 123, *Missa Solemnis*](http://imslp.org/wiki/Missa_solemnis,_Op.123_(Beethoven,_Ludwig_van))